# If $2^{\kappa}<\lambda$, how many subsets of size $\kappa$ are there of a set of size $\lambda$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Assume both cardinals are infinite. Also assume AC as needed.

So, the obvious bound is that there are no more than $\lambda^\kappa\leq 2^\lambda$ of them. But it seems there should be an easy bound smaller than this. I'm especially interested in seeing proofs of any better bound that are nice and short, even if they assume extra whirligigs.

Edit: By ``extra whirligigs'' I mean that I am willing to assume extra relationships between $\kappa$ and $\lambda$. I would prefer, as far as possible, to find an answer with $\lambda$ an arbitrary infinite cardinal. On the other hand, I'm really not too picky, and am as interested in seeing the argument techniques as getting "the best possible" bound.

Comment: Is $\lambda$ regular? Is $\kappa$ larger than the cofinality of $\lambda$ otherwise?

Comment: @Asaf: I'm willing to make such assumptions; they fall under the rather broad umbrella of what I'm classing as ``whirligigs.''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some basic observation:

1. If $\kappa\geq\lambda$ then $\lambda^\kappa=2^\kappa$, in which case $2^\lambda$ may be smaller or equal than the result. So we may assume from here on end that $\kappa<\lambda$.
2. It is consistent that $\kappa<\lambda\leq2^\kappa\leq2^\lambda$. However it is consistent that all the inequalities are sharp and $\lambda^\kappa=2^\kappa$. For example, consider the case where $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ and $2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_3$. Now take $\kappa=\aleph_0$ and $\lambda=\aleph_1$. The result is that $\lambda^\kappa=\aleph_2>\lambda$.
3. Even if we require that $2^\kappa<\lambda$ it is still possible that $\lambda<\lambda^\kappa$. If $\lambda$ is singular and its cofinality is $\leq\kappa$ then $\lambda^\kappa>\lambda$. In fact, in that case if the gap is larger than $1$ (i.e. $\lambda^\kappa>\lambda^+$) then we even have that $(\lambda^+)^\kappa>\lambda^+$ and that is a regular cardinal.

   This case is consistent, although now we need large cardinals to prove it.
4. It is also possible that $\kappa$ is sufficiently small (i.e. $\kappa<2^\kappa<\operatorname{cf}(\lambda)\leq\lambda$) and $\lambda^\kappa=\lambda<2^\lambda$. Of course under the same assumptions we can have $\lambda^\kappa=2^\lambda$, e.g. as in the case with $\lambda^+$ in the previous possible scenario.

So all in all there isn't much we can say. Cardinal exponentiation is a wildcard in set theory. There are ways to control it, but we don't consider the actual exponents, but rather all sort of "strangely defined objects" about subsets of $\lambda$ of size $\kappa$ and so on. To learn more about this you may want to read up on **PCF theory** which was developed in order to prove certain results of this flavor.

Comment: The reference to PCF Theory is extremely welcome. If I might further bother you, and do so in a vague way, I'd like your thoughts on what conditions we might put on the relationship between $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ so that we can say something about the number of subsets of $\lambda$ of size $\kappa$. Your answer (4) is along these lines, but you may have other thoughts also.

Comment: The whole point of this answer is to point out that there are really just three things we can definitely say for arbitrary infinite cardinal $\lambda$. The set of finite subsets of $\lambda$ is also of size $\lambda$; the set of subsets of size larger than $\lambda$ is empty (note that cardinal exponentiation is about functions, not subsets, which in this case clearly shows up as a big different -- there are no subsets of $\{0,1\}$ which are countably infinite, but there are continuum functions from $\omega$ to $\{0,1\}$); anything else is very unprovable, at least in a reasonable generality.